# Understanding the solution to this geometric problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> In the figure, $AB$ is the diameter of the circle with centre $O$. $APQ$ and $RBQ$ are straight lines. Find $\angle BPR$.
>
> [image]

I could not solve this question, and I do not understand the answer:

> $\angle APB = 90^\circ$ (rt. $\angle$ in a semicircle)
>
> $\angle{PRB} = 45^\circ$ ($\angle$s in same segment)
>
> $\angle{APR} = 25^\circ + 45^\circ = 70^\circ$
>
> $\angle{BPR} = 90^\circ - 70^\circ = 20^\circ$

I do not understand step $3$. Where do $25^\circ$ and $45^\circ$ come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [exterior angle property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_angle_theorem), applied to $\triangle PQR$,

$$\angle APR = \angle AQR + \angle QRP   $$

$\angle QRP = \angle PRB = 45^{\circ} $